# how to select specific column which is an object in jpa spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

well I have a doubt, i have a class like this:

```
@Entity(name = "movie_details")
@Getter @Setter
public class MovieDetailEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"movieDetails", "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"}, allowSetters = true)
    private MovieEntity movie;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "character_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"movies", "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"}, allowSetters = true)
    private CharacterEntity character;
}
```

And I just want to show the characters from a movie, but I don't want to show the id and the MovieEntity I just want to show CharacterEntity...

```
@Repository
public interface MovieDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<MovieDetailEntity, Long> {
    Page<MovieDetailEntity> findByMovie(Pageable pageable, MovieEntity movie);
}
```

And this query return a json like this

```
"content": [
        {
            "id": ...,
            "movie": {
                ...
            },
            "character": {
                ...
            }
        }
    ],
```

I was reading about making an interface dto with getters but didn't work for me

Comment: Create a class and use @Query annotation to define query and map with dto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have could solve it, i create a interface projection, like this...

```
public interface MovieCharactersDto {
    CharacterEntity getCharacter();
    interface CharacterEntity {
        Long getId();
        String getName();
        String getImage();
        BigDecimal getWeight();
        Integer getAge();
        String getStory();
    }
}
```

And the query was as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<MovieDetailEntity, Long> {
    Page<MovieCharactersDto> findByMovie(Pageable pageable, MovieEntity movie);
}
```

Comment: Note that Spring Data has limitations i.e. at a certain complexity, it will fetch entities and just wrap the entities in proxies that implement the interface. If you want a real solution that also improves performance by generating minimal queries, you should look at what Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views, which also has a Spring Data integration, has to offer: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to turn your entity into a DTO object that you can return. You'd need to create a new object like

```
public class MovieDetailDto {
    private CharacterDto;
}
```

You would then probably want to implement a setter and getter method for CharacterDto and create the `CharacterDto` class similarly to the `MovieDetailDto` class with the fields from CharacterEntity you want to return with setters and getters for them.

When you get back a MovieDetailEntity from your repository you can then just create a new CharacterDto for the CharacterEntity and set it in a new MovieDetailDto.